# Slack API: Is there a way to determine which user clicked on a button in an interactive message?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am new to Slack's API, so bear with me. I have a slack [button](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#button) that contains a simple webhook link which, when clicked, updates a record somewhere on my site. However, I need to determine which user clicked the button and send this info back to my site in order to fill out an updated_by field with the user's name. The only way I see to do this is to somehow update the post request body with a variable containing the user's name?

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle interaction with the buttton.

 https://api.slack.com/reference/interaction-payloads/block-actions

The **payload** received **contains** the **SlackId** of the user who clicked the button.